# Pass navigation in props to menu element in React Native and React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm adding a menu to every screen navigation header, so created a menu function that needs the `navigation` object to navigate to different screens based on the menu item tapped. But the `navigation.navigate` from `props` is `undefined`.

```
export default function GeneralMenu(props) {
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <Menu
        visible={showMenu}
        onDismiss={() => setShowMenu(false)}
        anchor={
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowMenu(true)}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="menu"
              size={30}
              style={{ color: 'white' }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }>
        <Menu.Item onPress={() => { console.log(props.navigation)}} title="Screen1" />
        <Menu.Item onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Screen1', {})}} title="Screen1" />
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );
```

Then I use it like this:

```
return (
    <Provider>    
        <NavigationContainer>
          
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeComponent}
              options={{ title: 'Home',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: 'red'
                },
                headerRight: (navigation) => <GeneralMenu navigation={navigation} />,
              }}
            />
            ... 
            ...
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
);
```

The `console.log()` when first menu item is tapped shows:

```
Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "tintColor": "#fff",
}
```

As you see there is no navigate property. Please, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are passing navigation through props. But for react-navigation to navigate to other screens (even from the components that are not screen themselves), you don't need to pass them through props.

You can basically access navigation object itself by using useNavigation hook like this:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and then wherever you need to use it, you can use it normally like:

```
navigation.navigate(Screen name goes here);
```

Comment: are u sure u can use it on navigator?

Comment: I'm glad you didn't ask about NavigationContainer (or maybe provider :)... but the basic idea is, as long as your component is inside a navigator (and of course a navigator needs navigationcontainer), the useNavigation hook will work. Besides, it makes no sense to call navigation from a navigator afaik

Comment: as dev404 suggested, I just stopped passing the navigator object for the menu, instead I used the hook. Things work.

Answer (score 1):

To get `navigation.navigate()` you would wanna use the function syntax of `options`, which receives an object that contains `navigation`, like so:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeComponent}
  options={({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "Home",
    headerTitleAlign: "center",
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
    headerRight: () => <GeneralMenu navigation={navigation} />,
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

its happen because u shadowing name `props`, it should be

```
<Menu.Item onPress={() => { console.log(props.navigation)}} title="Screen1" />

<Menu.Item onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Screen1', {})}} title="Screen1" />
```

Also

header right doesn't have navigation props
It should be like this

```
return (
    <Provider>    
        <NavigationContainer>
          
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeComponent}
              options={(navigation) => {
return { title: 'Home',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: 'red'
                },
                headerRight: () => <GeneralMenu navigation={navigation} />,
              }
}}
            />
            ... 
            ...
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
);
```

Comment: thank you TimoDevs, removed the shadowing props, but unfortunately still the same. the navigation object injected does not have what needed to navigate to another page when selecting a menu item. I updated the code.

Comment: Hey, i fix too my solution, pls read again

Comment: yup, it did the trick. Sorry for not choosing your answer, even though it works, my initial  approach of getting the navigation reference is not correct as stated in the answer I chose. Thx for the help

Comment: Lol that's not a trick, rather than u import and defining navigation, better u use like what i did

Comment: also u can't import and use `useNavigation` hook on navigator, it only can be import and use in screen...

Comment: by 'it did the trick' I meant that it worked with your approach. Also it makes sense what you said about passing (injecting) what I need vs defining Navigation and using the hook in my menu code. Since I'm still learning RN, I'm still not sure what the best pattern is.

Comment: u can't use `useNavigation` hook inside navigationContainer itself, it should import and use inside screen